# How do we make people answer tougher questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have been active on Stack Overflow, mostly in the Android tag. Whenever I check new questions, I see that if it is about any API that is easy to answer; people line up and such questions get more than three answers on average.
This rush also results in [the fastest gun in the west problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

(Because there are people who know/can figure out answers to such questions, but care more about earning reputation points (took it so seriously), so they wonder why to put so much effort in for the same reputation points while you can earn the same with less effort and time. So tougher questions remain less attended.

My point is, do we need to modify the system, or bias it towards tougher questions to have better incentive to answer them? 
(Like a 'tough flag', i.e. the more number of people mark it tough, the better goes the incentive).

Comment: Put a bounty on it ?

Comment: Do you have an example of one of those tougher questions?  If you're referring to obscure, highly-localized troubleshooting problems, those are posted on SO on the off-chance that the person with that exact bit of information the OP needs will stumble across his question and answer it.

Comment: I am looking through a good example for such question, but will post one such soon.

Comment: Quite a lot of people only answer tough questions that interest them enough. It takes more time than fgitw though, precisely because it's hard.  The onus is on the poster to make it obviously interesting *and provide an mcve that make answering it feasible*.

Comment: True that, these are people who love challenging their knowledge. However it is not true with most of them. Check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704451/rxjava-single-background-thread-scheduler
This is not the toughest one, but it talks about something that not everybody uses, so this question will definitely garner less attention than questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703207/activity-has-leaked-window-after-showing-a-toast (this is answered many times yet people won't mark it duplicate, but only answer it.)

Comment: That Q is 22 minutes old. The emails to tag subscribers won't even be sent for up to 24 hours. It doesn't look particularly tough or well presented either.

Comment: Apology for posting half comment, completed it now.

Comment: I think people would generally answer hard questions **because they enjoy it**; it's fun and interesting to learn new things, figure something out and help someone solve a tough problem. What more incentive is needed? As @RobertHarvey points out, some types of *"tough"* problems aren't really a good fit for the SO model (because really they're just *very specific* or *not well defined*), but those that are will generally get answered.

Comment: I do agree that a lot of people (even **experienced** SO-ians) answer questions that should be marked duplicates or closed otherwise. But in the example you gave, the answerers are fairly new and the one who provided the correct answer is very new so probably doesn't understand how it all works. *"this is answered many times yet people won't mark it duplicate"*. Did *you* flag to close as a dupe?

Answer (score 2):

I answer a fair amount of questions when I can find one that interests me ([here is a recent one which wasn't straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569668/is-there-an-impact-of-the-jquery-function-on-garbage-collection)). I think finding questions to answer is a problem for many users though (even myself), they answer posts that they find interesting and it can be difficult in the now nearly 10 million question context for a new interesting question to be asked about an existing technology.

Often what happens is a question is asked which is some sort of combination of several previously asked questions in some way, or in which the answers to several previously asked questions would be the answer. Even in this scenario users will post answers.

I think that if the question is tough, users will answer. However, the harder or narrower the scope of the question, the more limited the available list of users who are capable of answering becomes. Often it can also be a game of interpreting the OP's question as well, and without enough experience making that step of inference can be a barrier to answering.

For the most part, people answering questions do want to help, and they want to help in significant ways not just simple "you forgot a closing brace". In the end, I do not think that forcing people to answer tougher questions is a problem that Stack Overflow has nor needs to solve.

The real trick would be getting users to ask well constructed, [Short, Self Contained, Correct Examples](http://sscce.org/) of what their current situation is. Even tough questions can suffer from not following these guidelines (and sometimes not following them makes them even harder or nearly impossible to answer).